# Increasing luminosity does not produce desired effect

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing, luminance

```
    cvCvtColor(img,dst,CV_RGB2YCrCb);
    for  (int col=0;col<dst->width;col++) 
    { 
        for (int row=0;row<dst->height;row++) 
        { 
            int idxF = row*dst->widthStep + dst->nChannels*col; // Read the image data 
            CvPoint pt = {row,col};
            temp_ptr2[0] += temp_ptr1[0]* 0.0722 + temp_ptr1[1] * 0.7152 +temp_ptr1[2] *0.2126  ;   // channel Y 
        }
    }
```

But the result is this:

[image]

Please assist where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is *a lot* to say about this code sample:

- First, you are using the old C-style API (`IplImage` pointers, `cvBlah` functions, etc), which is obsolete and more difficult to maintain (in particular, memory leaks are introduced easily), so you should consider using the C++-style structures and functions (`cv::Mat` structure and `cv::blah` functions).
- Your error is probably coming from the instruction `cvCopy(dst,img);` at the very beginning. This fills your input image with nothing just before you start your processing, so you should remove this line.
- For maximum speed, you should invert the two loops, so that you first iterate over rows then over columns. This is because images in OpenCV are stored row-by-row in memory, hence accessing the images by increasing column is more efficient with respect to the cache usage.
- The temporary variable `idxF` is never used, so you should probably remove the following line too:

  ```
  int idxF = row*dst->widthStep + dst->nChannels*col;
  ```
- When you access image data to store the pixels in `temp_ptr1` and `temp_ptr2`, you swapped the positions of the `x` and `y` coordinates. You should access the image in the following way:

  ```
  temp_ptr1  = &((uchar*)(img->imageData + (img->widthStep*pt.y)))[pt.x*3];
  ```
- You never release the memory allocated for `dst`, hence introducing a memory leak in your application. Call `cvReleaseImage(&dst);` at the end of your function.